# Why automatic port forwarding? How to prevent VS Code from doing it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

My setup is VS Code with a dev container. When I start an application that produces output that looks like a URL, VS Code will extract the port number and automatically forward that port. This process is described in some detail [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143958).

My question is twofold:

1. What is the advantage of automatically forwarding ports?
2. How do I effectively prevent VS Code from automatically forwarding any port?

Solutions I considered and tested include using settings such as:

```json
{
   // Prevent VS Code's automatic port forwarding
   "remote.autoForwardPorts": false,
   "remote.restoreForwardedPorts": false,
   "remote.portsAttributes": {
      "1-65000": {
         "label": "Application",
         "onAutoForward": "ignore"
      }
   },
}
```

I have experimented with these settings at the user level, at the dev container level (aka remote), and at the workspace level. Furthermore, I've tried these settings in `devcontainer.json` as well. I've also rebuilt the dev container to ensure settings were applied.

However, I didn't have much luck with any of this. VS Code keeps automatically forwarding ports. I'm looking for a durable solution.

Comment: Did you try this [devcontainer.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108346#issuecomment-723134100) and rebuild?

Comment: @ikhvjs Yes, I rebuilt the dev container a few times along the way, too, but am not able to get a reliable consistent result. VS Code keeps forwarding ports.

Comment: What OS are you using? If you are using Windows, the source codes are in Windows filesystem or in WSL filesystem?

Comment: The dev container runs on Linux, VS Code frontend on Windows. I'm aware where to find the settings. I've updated them in four different places: user, workspace, dev container, and also in `devcontainer.json`. I have some dev containers where it works and some where it doesn't. I am looking for the determining factor, ideally other than a bug in VS Code.

Comment: @ikvvjs I tried that setting in [devcontainer.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108346#issuecomment-723134100) but not change in behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I added `"remote.autoForwardPorts": false` in the `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`. Currently the right place seems to be the following:

```
{
  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "settings": {
        "remote.autoForwardPorts": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I check with the [devcontainer.json reference documentation](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/) and [port attributes](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/#port-attributes).

I think you need the below settings in the `devcontainer.json`

> `otherPortsAttributes`: Default options for ports, port ranges, and hosts that aren’t configured using `portsAttributes`

> `onAutoForward`: A value of `ignore` means that this port should not be auto-forwarded at all.

```json
{
  "otherPortsAttributes": { "onAutoForward" : "ignore" }
}
```

Comment: @ikvhjs Thank you for the suggestion. I tried that but no change in behavior.

Comment: @Manfred, I did test it and it did work. If you specify any port mapping, you need to remove them first in your `devcontainer.json`

Comment: For me this worked as expected.